# CSS float causing paragraphs to be moved

Tags: css

When using the code below, I expect the title,login and sign up to be in the header div, however only the title seems to be, Im pretty sure it is the float:right that is causing the issue as it works fine when i remove that.

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%">
    <div id="header" style="background-color:#FFA500;padding:0;width:100%;">
        <h1 style="margin-bottom:0;">Title</h1>
        <p style="float:right;padding:5px;">login</p>
        <p style="float:right;padding:5px;">sign up</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

can someone explain why this is happening and maybe suggest how i can correct it?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`h1` is a block element..try by `display:inline;` for `h1`.

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/JBK4k/

Answer (score 1):

You are having that problem because:

1. `h1` has `display:block` default style, which will conquer the full width.
2. In child container, you just apply `float` for `p`, not to `h1` as well.

See, if you assign `float:left` to that `h1`, you will get the result as you wanted. It is because it has been floated to the left and the remaining space on the right will be occupied by the paragraphs with the styling `float:right`

So the edited code would be:

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%;">
    <div id="header" style="background-color:#FFA500;padding:0;overflow:hidden;">
        <h1 style="float:left;margin-bottom:0;">Title</h1>
        <p style="float:right;padding:5px;">login</p>
        <p style="float:right;padding:5px;">sign up</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

p/s: don't forget to add `overflow:hidden;` to `#header` in order to clear the floats.

Answer (score 0):

To explain what's happening, when you "float" something you're essentially pulling it out of the document flow so the containing div#header collapses down to the last non-floated element.  there are several ways to "clear the float" so that the parent container fully contains the floated elements.  You could float the parent container as mentioned above (floated elements will contain floated elements), or you could add overflow:hidden to the container (I do this a lot), or you could use the "easy clear" method which is probably the most popular these days.  If you do a search for "clearing floated elements" you will probably see more in depth explanations.

Answer (score 0):

If you give expecting height to the parent you don't need to worry about floats. try this add some height to parent element of the float elament

> height:30px;//give whatever height you want

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%">
   <div id="header" style="background-color:#FFA500;padding:0;width:100%; height:30px;">
      <h1 style="margin-bottom:0;">Title</h1>
      <p style="float:right;padding:5px;">login</p>
      <p style="float:right;padding:5px;">sign up</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

**OR**
You should clear the floats. Try this

> clear:both;// or give **clear:right** to clear only float:right or give **clear:left** to clear only float:right

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%">
   <div id="header" style="background-color:#FFA500;padding:0;width:100%">
      <h1 style="margin-bottom:0;">Title</h1>
      <p style="float:right;padding:5px;">login</p>
      <p style="float:right;padding:5px;">sign up</p>
      <div style="clear:both"></div><!--clear both floats-->
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need clear float,try this:

```
#header:after,
#hader:before{
   content:"";
   display: table;
}
#header:after{
   clear:both;
   overflow: hidden;
}
#header {
  zoom: 1;/*for ie6*/
}
```

Other solutions, please click [here](http://www.w3cplus.com/css/clear-float).